# Xamarin How to send a Post with my entrys

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I need to fill a form with inputs in Xamarin, and send them to my API page.

I already tried sending the data in "Postman" and it saved it correctly, but I would like to know how to send it from Xamarin.

Attention, I can read the data correctly from the application.

```
public class FuelPurchase
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string date{ get; set; }
    public int vueltametal { get; set; }
    public int amount{ get; set; }
    public string station{ get; set; }
    public string location{ get; set; }
}
```

And the form you create in Xamarin is this.

```
<Label Text="Fuel Purchase"/>
            <Label Text="Fecha">
            <DatePicker x:Name="Date"/>

            <Label Text="Station"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Station"/>

            <Label Text="Location"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Location"/>

            <Label Text="Amount"/>
            <Entry x:Name="amount" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
```

Comment: Postman includes code generators that can get you started:  Via UI: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/  Via SDK: https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/code-generators/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a static class that I use for API's. You can change the url to match yours if you only have one. Make sure to step through it and check that all of your "/"'s are in the right spot!

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using NGJS = System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBCS
{
    public class RestService
    {
        readonly HttpClient client;

        public RestService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = null,
                UseProxy = false
            });
        }

        #region GET
        public async Task<object> RefreshDataAsync(string url, string qs)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, qs));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    return await NGJS.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<object>(stream);
                }
            }
            //Error Handling here
            return null;
        }
        #endregion

        #region POST


        static void SerializeJsonIntoStream(object value, Stream stream)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false), 1024, true))
            using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.None })
            {
                var js = new JsonSerializer();
                js.Serialize(jtw, value);
                jtw.Flush();
            }
        }

        HttpContent CreateHttpContent(object content)
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = null;

            if (content != null)
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                SerializeJsonIntoStream(content, ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                httpContent = new StreamContent(ms);
                httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            }

            return httpContent;
        }

        public async Task PostStreamAsync(string url, object content)
        {
            string Url = url;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url))
            using (var httpContent = CreateHttpContent(content))
            {
                request.Content = httpContent;

                using (var response = await client
                    .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Successfully Sent");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: You will see a bunch of red lines in visual studio if you dont have the nuget packages downloaded that it needs, but don't fret. You just download them using the nuget PM and all will be well. Also check your permissions for internet and stuff. It should be on but just to make sure, give it a check.

Comment: I'm not sure why I dispose of the HttpClient on the POST and not the GET... LOL

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I save the entries as objects of my class?

Comment: You make a new instance of the object = `FuelPurchase fp = new FuelPurchase()
{
   fp.Date = Date.Date,
   fp.Amount = amount.Text,
   etc....
}
Then send the object in the Post method = RestService.PostStreamAsync(your url here, fp)

Comment: Just to clarify this only sends it to your endpoint, it doesn't save anything to the device, only to your server somewhere.

Comment: Hello, I tried but it gave me an error in the following line: using NGJS = System.Text.Json;

Comment: @AlejandroEmanuel Yes, you have to add the NuGet System.Text.Json

Comment: @AlejandroEmanuel If you have any more problems just let me know.

Comment: Thask for your good actitud. I did this:
Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.158:8000/CompraGasoil");
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);